# Dependencies between microservices

Tags: spring-cloud, microservices

I want to configure a simple microservice architecture with Spring Cloud.

I have started with 3 infrastructure components:
- Service Registry (SR)
- Config Server (CS)
- Auth Server (AS)

and this configuration:

SR and AS use CS to retrieve their configurations on startup.
CS and AS register themself on SR to be discoverable.

Now, a cyclic dependency between SR and CS cause an exception because one of them can not connect to the other.

There is a solution without remove this dependency? For example, waiting for the other service to be up and running?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you deploying these services?

Comment: Can you specify what spring components or otherwise you are actually using. E.g Eureka for SR, cloud config for CS...

Comment: are you writing these services yourself? I hope not because: Service Registries (Consul, Kubernetes etc.), Config Server (etcd etc.) and Authentictaion Sevrer (any oauth service) already exist!

Comment: I am using the spring cloud Eureka, config and security-oauth2

Comment: I have used spring retry in the service registry to wait config server to be up without exceptions. The problem remain when config server try to send heartbeat to service registry that in the meanwhile is yet in starting phase! PS: In this case, the autoconfiguration for spring retry doesn't work!